# MySQL UNION AND WHERE array EQUALs or is more

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm currently working on some script, but I don't know how to proceed further.

- I have an imploded array (1, 5, 3, 4, ..).
- Two tables where I need to use UNION to merge column `atribute`.
- And return one result where `atributes` are equal or greater with my array order by rand().

Is there some simple way to approach this?
I tried using IN() clause, but It will not return equal or greater results with my array.

```
SELECT av.sentence
    FROM atributes_workers AS a
    LEFT JOIN atributes_workers_sentences AS av ON a.id = av.parent
    LEFT JOIN atributes_workers_sentences_other_atributes AS avd ON av.id = avd.sentence_id
    UNION 
    WHERE atribute IN (1,5,3,4)
    ORDER BY RAND()
```

But it doesn't work.

`atributes_workers_sentences` does have one column with `atribute` too, that's why I need to search in two tables and merge these cols.

Comment: show some code so we can help you

Comment: updated, but little bit bad - not working..

Comment: I don't see any reason to be using UNION. Are you sure you know what UNION does? Also if multiple tables have an `atribute` column, you need to specify which table you are talking about in the WHERE clause. Maybe you want `WHERE a.atribute IN (...) OR av.atribute IN (...)`